# C++ tutorial on Diffie Hellman

Tags: c++, diffie-hellman

Is there a C++ tutorial for Diffie Hellman key exchange using OpenSSL? I keep searching and I can't find anything. If you know of a tutorial, I would be grateful for a link to it.  Thank you.

Comment: I think that most of the people here hate being pushed or seeing things like "????", "?!?!?!?!", etc. I, personally, avoid answering such questions...